# Unable to open a suspicious folder as an administrator

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I have a strange folder in my C: drive that is named "db0508036d5f02da1733769e". I've already run it through my anti-virus and malware scans and they have found no threats. Is anyone familiar with these types of folders? If so, what is this folder for?

I've tried opening the contents but it keeps telling me that "You don't currently have permission to access this folder." and "You have been denied permission to access this folder. To gain access to this folder you will need to use the security tab." However, when I am in the security tab and edit the permissions for Administrators or SYSTEM, the permission boxes are grayed out and only "Special permissions" is allowed.

Note: I am the Administrator of the computer and am running on Windows 7.

Here is a screenshot of this:
[image: Permissions for 1055]

Here is a view of the contents of the folder:
[image: Folder contents]

Comment: Could it be the setup of .NET framework? `NDP40-KB2656405-x64.exe is part of the .NET framework updates provided by microsoft company`. So lookup what kb2736428 is. I found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36350).

Answer (score 3):

@Rik is correct. The folder is an installation folder left over by Windows Update, likely for a .NET update/upgrade.

> The installers for the .NET Framework 3.0 and later use a different self-extracting EXE technology, which is why you have observed different behavior depending on what version of the .NET Framework you are trying to install.  The self-extracting logic for these versions of the .NET Framework does the following:
>
> - Find the drive on your system with the largest amount of free disk space
> - Create a randomly named folder on that drive
> - Extract the contents of the EXE to that folder
> - Run the setup EXE from within that folder
> - After the setup EXE returns, attempt to delete that folder
>
> [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/12/09/9188755.aspx?Redirected=true)

The folder can be deleted, but before you do, reboot your computer to make sure any pending installation from Windows Update is completed first, just in case.

You can also run the free version of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) which will safely delete any temporary .NET and Windows Update files automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of an Admin can't open a folder in Windows is because he's not the owner of the folder. On that same security-tab, click "Advanced", and check who it says the owner is under the Owner-tab.
If you're an admin, you can take ownership of the folder and then grant yourself all privileges on the Permissions-tab.

Be careful with taking ownership though, this can break stuff, and *you can't give ownership back to the original owner, it can only be taken*. These look like installation files for an update (like @Rik says). So I'm guessing it's not a problem in this case (correct me if I'm wrong).